# How to create a dynamic where clause?

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic-linq

in this below code

```
string cluase = string.Empty;
string whereValue = string.Empty;

foreach (var i in whereCluaseItems)
{
    if (cluase != "")
    {
        cluase += " and " + i.Name;
    }
    else
    {
        cluase = i.Name;
    }
    if (whereValue != "")
    {
        whereValue += "," + i.Value;
    }
    else
    {
        whereValue = i.Value;
    }
}

var result = context.vCatalogItemsDetails
                    .Where(cluase, whereValue) 
// since where syntax has to be like this : where("@landuageID=@0,categoryid=@1", 1,1)
.OrderBy("itemID")
.Skip((pageN - 1) * 10).Take(10);
```

cluase is a string and it contains
`"languageId=@0, categoryid=@1"`

whereValue is also a string and it contains 
`"1,1"`

i need to remove those quotation marks. how can i do it?

Comment: Here's a great article on CodeProject: [Build Where Clause Dynamically in Linq](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/582450/Build-Where-Clause-Dynamically-in-Linq).

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of "dynamic" where clause, there is often no need to use expression based features. You just have to realize that multiple `Where` calls can be composed.

For example:

```
public static IEnumerable<Person> Filter(this IEnumerable<Person> source, 
    string firstname, string lastname)
{
    if (firstname != null)
    {
        source = from person in source
                 where person.Firstname.Contains(firstname)
                 select person;
    }

    if (lastname != null)
    {
        source = from person in source
                 where person.Lastname.Contains(lastname)
                 select person;
    }

    return source;
}
```

The same technique works with `IQueryable<T>` too.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do that with help of [Dynamic LINQ](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library) library, it is then as simple as:

```
var result = context.vCatalogItemsDetails
                    .Where(cluase, whereValue) 
                    .Where("landuageID=1 AND categoryid=1")
                    .OrderBy("itemID")
                    .Skip((pageN - 1) * 10).Take(10);
```